# Ansible. Get a directory name out of "tar.gz" archive without decompressing

Tags: ansible, tar.gz

I am installing nexus using Ansible. Ansible task downloads the last version packed as "tar.gz" archive and unpacks it into the target directory. The archive contains two directories. For example:

```
/srv
  |- /nexus-3.34.0-01
  |- /sonatype-work
```

Then Ansible need to create a symbolic link. Like this:

```
/srv
  |- /nexus-3.34.0-01
  |- /sonatype-work
  |- ~nexus -> /srv/nexus-3.34.0-01
```

Ansible don't know the name of the nexus directory. It is not a problem, if we have only one of them:

```
- name : Find the name of the nexus directory
  ansible.builtin.find:
    paths: /srv
    patterns: 'nexus-*'
    file_type: directory
  register: nexus_dir

- name: Create a symbolic link for Nexus
  ansible.builtin.file:
    src: "{{ nexus_dir.files[0].path }}"
    dest: /srv/nexus
    state: link
```

THE PROBLEM IS: The directory `srv` already contains previous nexus installations. How can I look into the original archive to find the name of the current nexus directory?

Comment: You could look for the nexus-* directory with most recent mtime

Comment: guido offers a very good suggestion, using [`new_names | difference(old_names)`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.10/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#selecting-from-sets-or-lists-set-theory) can also work

Comment: In this very precise case, calling the uri giving `--/latest-unix.tar.gz` will answer with a redirect link to `.../nexus-x.y.z-unix.tar.gz`. You can simply rely on that version without having to open the archive. An example [here](https://github.com/ansible-ThoTeam/nexus3-oss/blob/0c6c4a4f4331a4b19287d4f488552778825bfd41/tasks/nexus_install.yml#L37-L54)

Comment: I cannot use the "last" directory. It is very possible I want to rollback to the previous version. I cannot use the "difference". It is very possible the directory was already created during the previous run of the script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution I found:

```
- name : Find the name of the nexus directory
  shell: tar --gzip --list  --file={{ filename_nexus }} | grep -o -E -m 1 ^nexus-[^/]+
  register: nexus_dir

- name: Print found nexus installation
  ansible.builtin.debug:
    msg: "Following nexus installation found: {{ nexus_dir.stdout }}"
```

where `grep -o -E -m 1` returns the first match of the provided regular expression.